# Tranform array of objects data in javascript to another form using ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

So i have the following data structure

```
var data = [
   {name:'AWB ', data:[12,13 ...]},
   {name:'CTS', data:[40,53 ...]}
   ]
```

I have another array that maps the names

```
var nameditems = [
    {name:'AWB', json_col:'awb_no'},
    {name:'CTS', json_col:'cts'}
 ]
```

As from the above example every data in each array object has two items or more

I want to transform the data to look like this

```
[

 {awb_no:12, cts:40},
 {awb_no:13, cts:53},
]
```

There are more columns but for brevity i just included the first two. Also data names are dynamic but the named_items json_col has the actual name to be in the key pair

So i have tried the following with es6

```
let resultarray = [];
const totalitems = data[0].data.length;
for (int i = 0; i < data[0].data.length; i++)
  data.forEach(item => {
    let jsoncolname = nameditems.find(col => col.name === item.name);
    console.log(jsoncolname, json_col) //how do i add as key below

    resultarray.push({}) //here am stuck
  })
```

Comment: Have the `data`-Parts the same length? It looks like you want to transform to `{awb_no: data[0], cts: data[0]}`, `awb_no: data[1], cts: data[1]` ?

Comment: Are the key names `awb_no` and `cts` fixed?

Comment: yes data always  has the same lengtjh

Comment: @lealceldeiro the names awb_no and cts are fixed  but the AWB and CTS are dynamic keep on changing. the awb_no and cts represents AWB and CTS respectively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `data` arrays have the same length over all items inside `data` array. You could reduce `nameditems` to another array by mapping correspondent `data` you find by `name`

```js
var data = [{
    name: 'AWB',
    data: [12, 13, 14]
  },
  {
    name: 'CTS',
    data: [40, 53, 67]
  }
]

var nameditems = [{
    name: 'AWB',
    json_col: 'awb_no'
  },
  {
    name: 'CTS',
    json_col: 'cts'
  }
]

console.log(
  nameditems.reduce(
    (items, {
      name,
      json_col: prop
    }) => data.find(item => item.name === name).data.map((value, index) => {
      const obj = items[index] || {} // pick existing item or create new
      
      obj[prop] = value // populate the prop
      
      return obj
    }),
    []
  )
)
```

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI Glad I could help.

Comment: How can i adjust your code above to first check the results of data.find that .data exists before doing the .data.map as i have another situation that i may need to check if data exists?

Comment: Extract `data.find(item => item.name === name)` to a variable and check it to be truthy. If not just return `items`.

Answer (score 1):

You could take an object for the mapped key names anf iterate the array and the data for new objects with assigned values.

```js
var data = [{ name: 'AWB', data: [12, 13] }, { name: 'CTS', data: [40, 53] }],
    nameditems = [{ name: 'AWB', json_col: 'awb_no' }, { name: 'CTS', json_col: 'cts' }],
    keys = Object.assign(...nameditems.map(({ name, json_col }) => ({ [name]: json_col }))),
    result = data.reduce((r, { name, data }) => {
        data.forEach((v, i) => (r[i] = r[i] || {})[keys[name]] = v)
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple ES6 alternative:

```
var data = [{name:'AWB', data:[12,13]}, {name:'CTS', data:[40,53]}];
var nameditems = [{name:'AWB', json_col:'awb_no'},{name:'CTS', json_col:'cts'}]

var nameditemsObj = nameditems.reduce((all, {name, json_col}) => {
    all[name] = json_col;
    return all;
}, {});

var result = data.reduce((all, {name, data:vals}) => {

    vals.forEach((val, i) => {
        all[i][nameditemsObj[name]] = val;
    });

    return all;

}, [...new Array(data.length)].map( _ => ({})));

console.log(result);
```